# Communication problem of ros2 humble

Tags: ros2, topic, communication

On the ROS2 humble version, we publish messages using the topic method, and there is a probability that the node subscribing to the topic will not receive the message. This situation usually occurs when the subscribing node is started, and once it hapened, it will continue to be unavailable,
Terminating the node with ctrl+c and restarting it will still result in a probability of not being able to subscribe to topic messages. When this situation occurs, enter the ros2 node list command to query the subscription node, and the result shows __UNKOWN_NODE_NAME,
Use the command ros2 topic echo to query and confirm that the publishing node is publishing messages normally. We attempted to change the single threaded callback method for nodes to a multi threaded executor and callback group approach, but it seems that there has been no improvement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.